# Reporting Services 2008 - The report server installation is not initialized

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am trying to set up Report Server 2008 on a separate machine to the Reporting Services databases which are on a SQL Server 2008 R2 machine.

I configure everything in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager (identical to a set up we have working on a different pair of servers).  The database connection test works fine, and the final "Progress and Finish" and screen shows "Success". However when I browse to the report server I get the error:

*"The report server installation is not initialized. (rsReportServerNotActivated)"*

I have seen a number of solutions online for this but they suggest using the **Initialization tab** on the Reporting Services Configuration Manager to initialize it. Or alternatively to use the **rsactivate** command.  Now in 2008 I can't seem to find either of these so I'm a bit stuck.

When I use the Reporting Services Configuration Manager I get the following errors in the Event Viewer:

> The application domain
>   WindowsService_1 failed to initialize.
>   Error:
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerNotActivatedException:
>   The report server installation is not
>   initialized.    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.b_*2()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.RevertImpersonationContext.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b__0(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Security.SecurityContext.Run(SecurityContext
>   securityContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.RevertImpersonationContext.Run(ContextBody
>   callback)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.GetEncryptionKey()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.ConnectStorage()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ServiceController.ServiceStartThread(Object
>   firstStart).

followed by:

> The application domain
>   WindowsService_1 failed to initialize.
>   Error:
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerNotActivatedException:
>   The report server installation is not
>   initialized.    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.b_*2()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.RevertImpersonationContext.<>c*_DisplayClass1.b__0(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Security.SecurityContext.Run(SecurityContext
>   securityContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.RevertImpersonationContext.Run(ContextBody
>   callback)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.GetEncryptionKey()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.ConnectStorage()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ServiceController.ServiceStartThread(Object
>   firstStart).

Is there another way I can initialize the report server installation?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I finally managed to get this working by going to the Reporting Services Configuration Manager > Encryption Keys > Delete Encrypted Content > Delete.

Not sure why this worked, but it did.

Just for completeness I have noticed that I still the get the following error in the Application Log, which luckily doesn't seem to cause any obvious problems for me, but remains nonetheless.

> Failed to unload app domain DefaultDomain.  The following exception occurred: Error while unloading appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131015).

If I find anything else I'll post back.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!  Note: For anyone curious, I'm not getting any errors in my Application Log since the removal of the Encryption content.

Comment: This worked for me even for SQL Server 2012 SSRS connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2 DB

Comment: Work like a charms! I facing this trouble after i finish upgraded my SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014.